# what exactly is $x$ in $x_i$?

Tags: notation, definition

In the Wiki page https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Indexed_family, the notation $x_i$ is used to denote the image of $i$ under the function $f$ ($f$ is a function from the $index$ $set$ $I$ to the $indexed$ $set$ $X$). I have a question about this index notation: what exactly is $x$ in $x_i$? Is it a function like $f$ ? The Wiki page doesn't answer my question, it only says:

> The symbol x is used to indicate that $x_i$ is an element of X.

Comment: Please provide some context for how the specific notation in question is used.

Comment: it's just a question on the index notation in general, like in any context (sequence, sets, ...), when we use the indexed notation like $x_i$ or $A_i$, what is $x$ and $A$?

Comment: a real sequence can be thought of as a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$

Comment: It can actually depend on the context.  Sometimes $x_1,\dots,x_{22}$ are the names of variables with no relationship between them.  Sometimes $x$ is a function with $x_i$ defined to mean $x(i)$. Sometimes it's something else (like for cofactor matrices). I think this question would be improved if you could point to some specific examples, otherwise it's too open-ended.

Comment: Since I'm learning discrete math, the context in my question is index notation in denoting indexed family. I forgot that $x_1$ and $x_2$ can simply be variables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the text you linked it clearly says:

> The symbol $x$ is used to indicate that $x_{i}$ is an element of $X$.

Therefore, I would argue that $x$ in that context is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), it's added for readability since $f(i)$ doesn't suggest that $f(i)$ is an element of $X$, while $x_i$ does. In this sense, $x$ itself isn't really anything on its own, it's a symbol, while $x_i$'s are elements of $X$. One could think something like this:

> For each $i\in I$ pick some element $x_i$ of $X$. Now, define function
> $f\colon I \to X$ by the formula $f(i) = x_i$.

However, the notation $i\mapsto x_i$ also suggests that we can treat $x$ as a function, in this case the same function as $f$. In that sense, $x$ is another name for $f$. This would be the same as in notation for sequence. When we write: "let $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $X$", we mean: "let $x\colon \mathbb N \to X$ and let us write $x_i$ instead of $x(i)$."

Whatever interpretation you pick, in the end of the day, indexed family is formally the same as function, but we just like to think of these differently because we are humans, and for things to make sense to us, we need to attach some stories to describe what we intend to do with some mathematical formalism.

Comment: So in the first interpretation, all the $x_i$'s are just variable names, and asking what $x$ is in all the $x_i$'s is the same as asking what $a$ is in the variable $abc$, right? I guess I find it weird because that's like a "formula" for creating variable names instead of explicitly showing them (like $x_1$ and $v_2$).

Comment: @ncc291203, yes, something like that. It's common to use subscripts to distinguish your variables since there are only finitely many letters in any alphabet we have and in any formal theory we want infinitely many. Perhaps this sentence from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Alphabet) will be helpful: "As with all formal languages, the nature of the symbols themselves is outside the scope of formal logic; they are often regarded simply as letters and punctuation symbols."

Comment: But, really, what's the difference between forming letters like $x_1$ and $x_2$ based on symbol $x$ and forming letters č and ć based on symbol c in some variants of Latin alphabet?